# DjangoRestFramework / Django Class Based Views - How to make it redirect to login page if 403 error is raised

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-class-based-views, django-rest-auth

These are my views:

```
# This view is accessed by going to "/CMS/app"
class AppPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "app.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AppPageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

# This view is accessed by going to "/user/:user_id"
class user_detail(APIView):
    """
    Get, update or delete a specific user.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I access either of these views by going to their URLs, I get the default DjangoRestFramework page which says:

```
User Detail
Get, update or delete a specific user.

GET /CMS/users/8
HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Is it possible for me to change it so that instead of showing the default DRF page, make it redirect to the login page? (The login page URL is "/login").

Note: I am using the Django TemplateView for one view and the DRF APIView for the other, but both redirect to the DRF default 403 page when I try to access their URLs without being logged in.

Comment: It does not make sense for an API to redirect.  API are for developers to use, they are internal to the application and a redirect is when a browser uses the app, so that a person can fill in details. API should raise an error (which is what its doing, correctly).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid When I try a GET request by doing $http.get("/CMS/users/8") using AngularJS, then I do want it to return the 403 with a JSON message. However, I don't want the default DRF page to show up if users go directly to the URL using their web browser (My concern is that I don't want end users to accidentally end up on a DRF page which says "HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN Content-Type: application/json Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS Vary: Accept" because they'll get confused). Anything I can do about my concern? Can I show a simple "403 Click here to Login" page somehow?

Comment: I suppose the real question you are asking is - How can I detect that a user typed in the URL or it came from Angular?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Even if I knew that the user typed it in the URL, what are my options? Have an if statement in my view which says "if user typed it in the URL, redirect to the login page OR load a '403 Click here to login' template"? Because wouldn't that option not make sense either since my API is in the end, redirecting? I think my real question then, is - How can I show a customized 403 page rather than the default DRF page?

Comment: @user2719875 if you are using Angular for the front end of the application you can use an interceptor to redirect the user to your login page by checking the response code from the api.

Comment: @PieterHamman Correct, but suppose the user goes directly to the URL from the browser (goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/CMS/users/8). This URL links to the Django back end, which checks that the user is not authenticated, and then calls the default DRF page which shows the 403 error on client side. From my understanding, AngularJS doesn't play a part in this. When will the interceptor be used? The default DRF page doesn't use AngularJS, only my customized template pages do.

Comment: @user2719875 as far as I understand the DRF docs you can use 'TemplateHTMLRenderer' and specify a template the view needs to render (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer). And then DRF will use the normal django 403.html template (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#html-error-views)

Comment: If the user then goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/CMS/users/8 they will see your 403.html template.

Comment: @user2719875 another point to add is that you can also override the 'user_detail' view's dispatch method and redirect to the login page if the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the TemplateHTMLRenderer to your view renderer_classes, this will enable you to use the django 403.html template when an user goes to the url and the user is not authenticated. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer

```
class user_detail(APIView):
    """
    Get, update or delete a specific user.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    # Add TemplateHTMLRenderer to your view renderer_classes
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: As BurhanKhalid mentioned, I don't want to change my RESTful API / Views to redirect anywhere. I think it's best if I make my own customized 403.html page as you mentioned in the comments. Which option do you think is better for a RESTful API? (To redirect to a login URL or to create my own custom 403.html page which says "Click here to login"?)

Comment: @user2719875 I would just leave the default view as is, but if you are worried about someone accidentally going to the url you can setup the custom template. I would not recommend doing the doing the redirect as it's unexpected behavior from a rest service.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. You can edit your answer to include the "setting up custom template" part and I'll mark it off as the answer.

Comment: Just to confirm, the only thing which changes when adding the JSONRenderer / TemplateHTMLRenderer is that Django returns 403.html instead of the default DRF 403 page, right? Everything else remains the same (i.e when talking to the API using JS etc.)?